# placing origin at end of Bezier Curve

Tags: bezier-curves, origin

i have created a bezier curve, to make a corrugated sheet, and i am then trying to slide a thin cube mesh. i have placed the origin at one end of the the cube mesh and am trying to do the same with the bezier curve, but it will not move to the cursor which i have placed at the end point of the curve! how can i trick it into doing what i want, or any other method. Running OSX 10.15.6 and 2.83.3

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few ways to do it:

1. Go to Preferences > Add-ons and search for "Curve Tools" and activate the Add Curve: Curve Tools add-on by checking the box next to it. In the 3D Viewport press <kbd>N</kbd> to extent the Tool Shelf and click the Edit tab. Then go to Curve Tools > One Curve and click the "Set origin to spline start"-button.
2. Select the curve, go into Edit Mode. Select the starting vertex. press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, and choose Cursor to Selected. Go into Object Mode. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> (default search key) and type "Set Origin" and choose Origin to 3D Cursor.
3. In the 3D Viewport Header click the Snapping-button. (It is the icon next to the little magnet icon.) Choose Snap to Vertex. Then in the same header click Options and check the box next to Origins (uncheck it when you're done). Now hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or click the magnet icon) while moving the origin to snap it to the starting vertex.

Comment: thanks for your help, i have now got where i need to go.